# Why does my apps stop working when I click a button to call second activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a simple apps where on the main tab, I have a button. On clicking the button it is suppose launch another tab. However when I click the button, the screen goes blank and it says:

> Unfortunately appname has stopped

Where did I go wrong?

Code snippets include:

1. MainActivity.Java

   ```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
           return true;
   }

   public void serveMenu(View view) {
     // Do something in response to button
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServeMenuActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);

     }
       }
   ```
2. ServeMenuActivity.Java

   ```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;

      public class ServeMenuActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_serve_menu);
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.serve_menu, menu);
   return true;
    }

      }
   ```
3. AdriodManifest.xml

   ```
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity
       android:name="com.mywinsystems.tkrctennistips.ServeMenuActivity"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_serve_menu" >

   </activity>
   ```

Comment: You need to look in your logcat (adb logcat from the command-line.  I bet it is a NULL Pointer

Comment: If you show us your **logcat** then it'll be more helpful to solve your problem faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
10-06 17:30:41.249: D/OpenGLRenderer(18009): Enabling debug mode 0 10-06 17:31:46.774: D/AndroidRuntime(18009): Shutting down VM 10-06 17:31:46.774: W/dalvikvm(18009): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4108f2a0) 10-06 17:31:46.784: E/AndroidRuntime(18009): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-06 17:31:46.784: E/AndroidRuntime(18009): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method ServeMenu(View) in the activity class com.mywinsystems.tkrctennistips.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
```

According to your locgcate above 
try to rename the

```
public void serveMenu(View view) {
  // Do something in response to button
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServeMenuActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

  }
```

to

```
public void ServeMenu(View view) {
  // Do something in response to button
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServeMenuActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

  }
```

Comment: thelogcate is too long to cut n paste. How do I attach a file here ?

Comment: 10-06 17:30:41.249: D/OpenGLRenderer(18009): Enabling debug mode 0
10-06 17:31:46.774: D/AndroidRuntime(18009): Shutting down VM
10-06 17:31:46.774: W/dalvikvm(18009): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4108f2a0)
10-06 17:31:46.784: E/AndroidRuntime(18009): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 17:31:46.784: E/AndroidRuntime(18009): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method ServeMenu(View) in the activity class com.mywinsystems.tkrctennistips.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'

Comment: Basbous, a silly question. I seem to have closed my corresponding XML files. Where can I find them in Eclipse :-[

Comment: @CHChee res/Layout Folders

Answer (score 0):

check if onClick serveMenu added on main.xml button ie `android:onClick="serveMenu"`

Comment: I don't think that's an issue that will not generate any error to force close the app

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid I think it might be.

Comment: If **android:onClick="serveMenu** is not defined then the button will not work on click and that doesn't create any error.

Comment: How can I capture logcat ?
if I am in workspace\myproject:\ adb locgat 

I have a very long list and trying to pipe it to a txt fiel it was more than 2Mb long :-(